# priority-web-sdk: No data from getRows

Tags: javascript, erp

I'm [formStart](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/global/#formStart)ing a form and calling [getRows](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#getRows)(0). I'm not sure if the [getRows](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#getRows) parameter is 1 or 0 based (to start reading from the first row), but I've tried both with the same results described below.

```
    function priorityReady() {          
        login(config).then(
            function(){
                formStart('CUSTOMERS', showMessage, updateFields, config.company).then(
                    function(appgen){
                        appgen.getRows(1).then(
                            function(rows) {
                                console.log(rows);
                            }, showMessage
                        )
                    }, showMessage
                )
            }, showMessage
        )               
    }
```

The [Rows](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#Rows) result from [getRows](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#getRows) contains no records... any ideas please?

---

Update 2

I've added the company to the [formStart](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/global/#formStart) call and am now using 1 as the [getRows](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#getRows) parameter. Unfortunately there are still no records returned.

If I set autoRetrieveFirstRows = 1 however, I get an API error.

```
{type: "apiError", 
code: "exception", 
message: "(TypeError) : g is not a function", 
form: Object, 
fatal: false}
```

Comment: Does this occur only for the APPGEN form or it repeats for other forms as well?

Comment: Same for all forms, I tried `CUSTOMERS` and `DOCUMENTS_Q` too. All have data in Priority.

Comment: First thing - to get results from the first row you need to send 1 to `getrows`. About the issue - you need to send a company name to `formstart`. If that doesn't solve it then try starting the form with `autoRetrieveFirstRows=1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rows are only returned to getRows when the formStart call specifies the autoRetrieveFirstRows as 1. e.g.

```
formStart('CUSTOMERS', showMessage, updateFields, config.company, 1)
```

There was a confirmed bug in the version 1.5 package (thanks to @Leor for assistance with this) where specifying the autoRetrieveFirstRows caused the formStart function to fail.

This was resolved in version 1.6 of the package, which can be referenced like so...

```
<script src=
    "https://cdn.priority-software.com/upgrades/var/api/head/priorityapp.nocache.js">
</script>
```